# Managed Package effected by Salesforce release versions

Tags: managed-package, winter17

After creating a new package of my managed product I have encountered an issue where this package cannot be installed in many customer environments. This package was created in a Winter 17 environment therefore cannot be installed in an environment with a lower Salesforce release version.

Comment: If you could precisely tell what was the error when you tried installing ,we could definitely help you

Comment: @MohithShrivastava, There is not much anybody can do in this case but wait for SF to roll out Winter 17 to the Org I am looking to upgrade.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After contacting Salesforce, they notified me that this issue is considered as their ["blackout period"](https://partners.salesforce.com/partnerAlert?id=a033000000C85ZDAAZ) and the behaviour I am seeing is referred to as "working as designed".

> I took notice that your packaging org is on our Winter '17 release. As the affected org is on Summer '16, this behavior is considered "working as designed". A package cannot be installed in an org where the packaging org is on a newer release. This is called our "blackout period". The affected org will have to wait until it is updated to Winter'17 for your package to install. Here is a link to where you can see the release schedule, click on the instance number and look for a circled date and for "Winter 17 Major Release".

Looks like some of my customers cannot get the latest version of my product until Salesforce have rolled [Winter 17](https://status.salesforce.com/status) onto their instance.

Comment: Unfortunately, this happens every blackout period and you can do nothing but wait

Comment: @TSmith do you want to accept your own answer and get this one out of the unanswered questions queue.